# Java generics - putting and retrieving implementations of generic interface from map

Tags: java

I've got a question about java generics. Lets say I created this simple interface:

```
public interface ToString {

    String toString(Message message);
}
```

and class which implements this:

```
public class GoldMessageToStringer implements ToString  {

    @Override
    public String toString(Message message) {
        GoldMessage myMessage = (GoldMessage) message;
    }
}
```

I'm instantinating the Map to hold my ToString inplementations, so I can fetch them quickly and "safe" cast:

```
private static final Map<Message.Type, ToString> toStringer = initializeToStringers();

private static Map<Message.Type, ToString> initializeToStringers() {
   Map<Message.Type, ToString> map = new HashMap<>();
   map.put(Message.Type.A, new GoldMessageToStringer();
   return map;
}

String toStringMessage(Message message) {
   toStringer.get(message.getType()).toString(message);
}
```

What is ugly to me is the cast in `GoldMessageToStringer` so I decided to parametrize `ToString` interface so I can use types in implementations:

```
public interface ToString<T extends Message> {

    String toString(T message);
}

public class GoldMessageToStringer implements ToString<GoldMessage>  {

    @Override
    public String toString(GoldMessage message) {
        GoldMessage myMessage = message;
    }
}
```

But now I cannot supply or get or put ToString implementations into map (3rd snippet) or at least im ending with unchecked cast in best case because of type incompatibility. Im probably mixing generics with inheritance what is unallowed in Java right? How to do it according to best / common practices?

1st attempt - without specyfing generic type:

```
private static final Map<Message.Type, ToString> toStringer = initializeToStringers();

private static Map<Message.Type, ToString> initializeToStringers() {
   Map<Message.Type, ToString> map = new HashMap<>();
   map.put(Message.Type.A, new GoldMessageToStringer();
   return map;
}

String toStringMessage(Message message) {
   toStringer.get(message.getType()).toString(message); // unchecked cast
}
```

2nd attempt - generic type specified:

```
private static final Map<Message.Type, ToString<Message>> toStringer = initializeToStringers();

private static Map<Message.Type, ToString<Message>> initializeToStringers() {
   Map<Message.Type, ToString<Message>> map = new HashMap<>();
   map.put(Message.Type.A, new GoldMessageToStringer(); // not compiles, requring ToString<Message>, got GoldMessageToStringer
   return map;
}

String toStringMessage(Message message) {
   toStringer.get(message.getType()).toString(message); 
}
```

3rd attempt - specifing type boundary:

```
 private static final Map<Message.Type, ToString<? extends Message>> toStringer = initializeToStringers();

    private static Map<Message.Type, ToString<? extends Message>> initializeToStringers() {
       Map<Message.Type, ToString<? extends Message>> map = new HashMap<>();
       map.put(Message.Type.A, new GoldMessageToStringer(); 
       return map;
    }

    String toStringMessage(Message message) {
       toStringer.get(message.getType()).toString(message);  // not compiles, Message cannot be applied to ? extends Message
    }
```

4rd attempt - unchecked cast, the cleanest imho:

```
private static final Map<Message.Type, ToString<Message>> encoders = initializeToStringers();

String toStringMessage(Message message) {
    toStringer.get(message.getType()).toString(message);
}

private static Map<Message.Type, ToString<Message>> initializeToStringers() {
    Map<Message.Type, ToString<Message>> toStringers = new HashMap<>();
    put(toStringers, Message.Type.A, new GoldMessageToStringer());
    return encoders;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static <T extends Message> void put(Map<Message.Type, ToString<T>> map, MessageType type, ToString toStringer) {
    map.put(type, toStringer);
}
```

Comment: @sprinter ops, my mistake, fixed thanks

Comment: Could you include the 'unchecked cast' error you are seeing? It's possibly that you just need to include a type wildcard in your map: at the moment you are using a raw type.

Comment: Not really clear, but what about defining the map in this way:  Map<Message, ToString<GoldMessage>> map = new HashMap<>();

Comment: If you're mixing multiple types of `ToString` sub-classes in the same map, then you have no choice but to cast somewhere, somehow. Can you refactor your `GoldMessageToStringer` class (and its siblings) to *not* to make them work with just a `Message` object?

Comment: I updated my question. What do you exactly mean @ernest_k ? Could you show some simple example for this refactor?

Comment: @minizibi I mean, as in your initial version... why does `GoldMessageToStringer` need a `GoldMessage`? Can you make it so it can work just with the api of `Message`? (i.e., take polymorphism to your advantage)

Comment: well I dont think so because a Message is interface exposed to client API and I need one property which is in this specific GoldMessage if I put this property to Message it breaks my api. So there is an object which has 10 properties lets say but I show only five (defined in interface) to outside world

Comment: If its not possible its okay I will stay with 4rd version probably, but @ernest_k can I ask you about some tip, where to look for explanation of this behavior? Is it just about contravariance and Substitution Principle?

Comment: Make the key type `ToString<?>`. But honestly, the cleanest way was before you made `ToString` generic.